# How to extend a simple RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

We are using the following rules to rewrite this:

```
http://ourdomain/dev/client/photolibrary-europe-paris
```

to this:

```
http://ourdomain/dev/client/photolibrary.php?katid=paris
```

and this:

```
http://ourdomain/dev/client/photolibrary-europe-paris-city
```

to this:

```
http://ourdomain/dev/client/photolibrary.php?katid=paris&shootingid=city

RewriteRule ^photolibrary-([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ photolibrary.php?katid=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^photolibrary-([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ photolibrary.php?katid=$2&shootingid=$3 [NC,L]
```

However, our URLs sometimes look like this:

```
http://ourdomain/dev/client/photolibrary-europe-paris-city-right
```

which we need to convert to this:

```
http://ourdomain/dev/client/photolibrary.php?katid=paris&shootingid=city-right
```

Any ideas on how we can achieve this? Many thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can include the `-` character as part of the last grouping:

```
RewriteRule ^photolibrary-([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ photolibrary.php?katid=$2&shootingid=$3 [NC,L]
```

So that `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` can match `city-right`.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes it's just too easy!